# Colour space range

Tags: matlab, colors

Currently, I use the `c=makecform('lab2srgb')` and `RGB=applycform(LAB,c)` method provided by MATLAB in order to convert LAB colour space to RGB colour space. However, I didn't know what is the actual range of LAB value. I review few of the post through Google, but there are no any defined range for that in MATLAB. I am wondering how the range should set for the L, a* and b* component of the LAB colour space.

Anyone know how I can know it or any method to test it in order to find out the range?

Comment: The [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/makecform.html) suggest you use the [`lab2rgb`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/lab2rgb.html) function instead

Comment: @Dan Introduced in R2014b. Maybe OP doesnt have it.

Comment: Why do you want to set a range? Just apply the cform

Comment: I don't understand your question, about what range are you talking?

Comment: The Lab colour space should having a range so that we can set the maximum a or b. After that, we only use that  `lab2rgb` function to convert the maximum a or b to RGB. I want to know the range of it. Whether Matlab defined it as -100/100 or -128/127 or others.